# problem to install webdm on Ubuntu Core 16

Tags: ubuntu-core

Someone can explain because I've received that error when try to install webdm?

```
$: snap install webdm

error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Mount snap "webdm" (24) (installation not allowed by "snapd-control" plug rule of interface "snapd-control")
```

thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

webdm was the previous name of snapweb.

Try instead:

```
snap install snapweb
```